# Callback function in aurelia js

Tags: aurelia

Am new to aurelia js. Here, i need to do callback in aurelia js .
Here is the code i tried,
**file.js**

```
this.commonFunctions.get_alrdyShrdUser(this.alrdyshardAry,function(err,result){
        if(!err){
            console.log("err,result",err,result);
            this.sharedAlrdy =  result;
        }else{

        }
    });
```

**commonFunctions**

```
get_alrdyShrdUser(docids,callback){
     this.httpValueConverter.call_http('sharing/users/list','POST',docids,'test')
        .then(data => {
        if(data.meta && data.meta.statusCode == 200) {
        return callback(null,data.sharedUsers)
        }
    });
}
```

Here all works fine, callback function also returned value, but i can't assign value to a aurelia varibale(**this.sharedAlrdy**).It throws error, **Cannot set property 'sharedAlrdy' of undefined**. Is that any other way to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Aurelia. You are just having a typical JavaScript problem with `this`.

Since you are using Aurelia, I assume that is ES6 code and you have arrow function support. Use arrow function in function callbacks and you won't have problems with capturing `this`:

```js
this.commonFunctions.get_alrdyShrdUser(this.alrdyshardAry, (err, result) => {
    if (!err) {
        console.log("err, result", err, result);
        this.sharedAlrdy = result;
    } else {

    }
});
```

For more details on arrow functions and `this`, take a look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this).

Comment: how to change this one to es6 formate `$('.fb_folder_container').on('scroll', e => {
        if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
            this.loadMoreData();
        }
    });
`

Comment: Since you are using arrow function, `this` refers to the parent scope and not to an element. In this case, create a variable for element up front `let $element = $('.fb_folder_container');` and then use that in the code: `$element.on('scroll', e => { if ($element.scrollTop() + $element.innerHeight() >= $element.scrollHeight) { this.loadMoreData(); });` - something like that, you can do `console.log()` within the function to check the values. BTW, I usually encapsulate that functionality into component - `infinite-scroll`, so it's reusable on multiple pages.