# How to get the result of login error (from login.ts) to login.html

Tags: aurelia

I am new to Aurelia and have some background in Javascript. In particular, I am taking inspiration from https://blog.rackspace.com/part-2-building-serverless-architecture-aws and https://github.com/auth0/aurelia-quote-app to build a merge of two.

I am able to successfully to make call to AWS Cognito and get different validation  results. I know that these are successful by having the developer console open in firefox to monitor console.logs for different scenarios.

For example I get different responses in console.log:

1. users that exist in Coginto but wrong password: "NotAuthorizedException: Incorrect username or password."
2. Users that don't exist in Cognito: "UserNotFoundException: User does not exist."
3. Users with correct password: get the JWT token

In my login.html, I intend to display the login error through the ${loginError} variable

```
  -- login.html

  <form role="form" submit.delegate="loginUser()">
       ...
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
  </form>
  ...
  <div class="alert alert-danger" >${loginError}</div>
  ...
```

so that I can display the exceptions that occur in login.ts through the html by binding

In my login.ts,  I call cognitoUser.authenticateUser in the following manner.

```
--login.ts
export class Login {
     ...
     isUserAuthenticated = false;
     ...
     loginError = '';
     ...
     loginUser() {
        cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
          onSuccess: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            this.isUserAuthenticated = true;
            location.assign('#/home');  
          },
          ...
          onFailure: function(err) {
             console.log(err);
             this.loginError = err;
             this.isUserAuthenticated = false;
           }
           ...
```

**When this.loginError is set to err, it is not reflected in the html. This is likely because of the nature of the call-back functions in Javascript...I am trying to get my head around how to solve this; given that the html needs to display the loginError and the actual error comes out of a callback function in authenticateUser. I am confident that this.isUserAuthenticated will face the same issue.**

On the positive side, when the login is successful, the  location.assign('#/home'); does get executed (even if this.isUserAuthenticated = true; does not get reflected in the main login.ts)

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 4):

Answering my own question, thanks to help from [Callback function in aurelia js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40790615/callback-function-in-aurelia-js)

Essentially use the ES6 and arrow functionality for access to the "this".

```
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
    onSuccess: (result) => {
    console.log(result);
    this.isUserAuthenticated = true;
    location.assign('#/home');  
    },
...
    onFailure: (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    this.loginError = err;
    this.isUserAuthenticated = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: You got it. When you use the `function()` syntax, `this` has a local scope limited to only that function. When you use the thick arrow `() => {}` syntax, `this` connects with the parent scope.